# How to render pdf from HTML using CakePdf? I followed the instructions given in github but getting an error 'Failed to load PDF document'?

Tags: php, pdf, cakephp-3.0, wkhtmltopdf, cakephp-3.6

I installed the plugins of CakePdf using composer. So in my vendor folder I have CakePdf plugin & other dependencies.

I downloaded wkhtmltopdf and installed it in a directory. The directory is `C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe`

Next by running the command `./bin/cake plugin load CakePdf -b` I added the plugin in `src/application.php`

```
$this->addPlugin('CakePdf', ['bootstrap' => true]);
```

Then I wrote the below line in `config/routes.php` just before `Router::scope`

```
Router::extensions(['pdf']);
```

And in `config/bootstrap.php`

```
Configure::write('CakePdf', [
    'engine' => [
        'className' => 'CakePdf.WkHtmlToPdf',
        'binary' => 'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe',
        'options' => [
            'print-media-type' => false,
            'outline' => true,
            'dpi' => 96
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Now in my `abc` controller `view` action I wrote

```
$this->viewBuilder()->options([
        'pdfConfig' => [
            'orientation' => 'portrait',
            'filename' => 'Invoice_' . $id.'.pdf'
    ]
]);
```

I have also created `view.ctp` inside `src/Templates/abc/pdf/view.ctp` and a `default.pdf` layout inside `src/Templates/Layout/pdf/default.ctp` .

Now when I go to `localhost/abc/view/1.pdf`, I get an error saying `Failed to load PDF document`!

[Failed to load the PDF document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTrrq.jpg)

> I would really like to know what could have went wrong and how I can fix it to work?

Comment: You have `'filename' => 'Invoice_' . $id.'.pdf'` but you are looking for `localhost/abc/view/1.pdf`.

Comment: @Tigger Can't I have the file name as my wish!

Comment: You can set the file name to what ever valid characters you want. Re-read what I wrote. The file name you have set (as an example) `Invoice_1.pdf` but that is nothing at all like `1.pdf` (what you are looking for).

Comment: No, the options are correct as they are, the `filename` option will be used in the response's `Content-Disposition` header, it has nothing to do with the request URL. Make sure that you have debug mode enabled, and check your logs for possible errors. Also download the invalid PDF and look at its source to figure what output exactly is being produced.

Comment: That's what I was wondering about `'filename'`! Debug mode is enabled, but no error logs. Downloaded the pdf and opened it in notepad, It's plain Html. @ndm

Comment: That sounds like the plugin isn't loaded. Make sure that the `$this->addPlugin()` call in your `Application` class' `bootstrap()` method is actually being invoked.

Comment: Here's my all settings related to CakePdf `https://gist.github.com/azmain/e2456a8cf769bc10706a575332db2c84` How can I make sure that if this plugin is being called?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had AdminLTE layout and template files set up in AppController's beforeRender method so it was overriding my layout and template just before providing the view.

I altered beforeRender method of AppController class to something like this:

```
    public function beforeRender(Event $event)
    {
        switch ($this->request->params['_ext']) {
          case 'pdf':
            break;
          default:
            $this->viewBuilder()->setTheme('AdminLTE');
            $this->viewBuilder()->setClassName('AdminLTE.AdminLTE');
            break;
        }
    }
```

and CakePdf plugin started to generate PDF's like it should.

Comment: what version of cakephp do you use? I would guess 3? It doesn't seem to work with 4

Comment: Yes I was using 3.x don't remember which one. I'm not sure if AdminLTE package is compatible with 4.x

Comment: Thanks @kuvukala

I'm using cakePHP 4 and the AdminLTE theme and I could not get the PDF rendered.

Using your idea, for the time being what I've done is to reset the view builder class name, in the controller where I want a PDF printed (in my application it's just one controller which provides PDFs), like this:


    public function beforeRender(\Cake\Event\EventInterface $event)
    {
        parent::beforeRender($event);
        if ( $this->getRequest()->getParam('_ext','') === 'pdf' ) {
            $this->viewBuilder()->setClassName('CakePdf.Pdf');
        }
    }